# problem with hook for react-native async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I try to load a fontfamily, I used hook with async function but I have some errors:

```
function Button(props: TouchableOpacityProps & ButtonProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadFont() {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        gotham_medium: require("../../assets/GothamMedium_1.ttf")
      });
    }
    loadFont()
  }, []);
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity {...props} style={styles.button}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

I imported Font from expo and useEffect from react but I have this error.
[error on the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdhmQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have on my app in case it may help someone.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadFonts = async () => {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'pokeh': require('../../assets/fonts/pokeh.ttf'),
      });
      setFontReady(true);
    };
    loadFonts();
  }, []);
```

And these two on the top after installing expo-font with npm

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
```

Under this tree structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your error might be generated by the wrong React version. Are you sure you're using at least Expo SDK 33?

If that's not the issue, I believe it might be easier if you load all assets earlier in the process. Expo provides an `AppLoading` component that takes a `startAsync` prop, which can be used to resolve all async promises pretty easily.

So your `App.js` could look like:

```
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function App(props) {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);

  if (!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadResourcesAsync}
        onError={handleLoadingError}
        onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome to your Expo app</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

async function loadResourcesAsync() {
  await Promise.all([
    Font.loadAsync({
      'gotham-medium': require('./assets/GothamMedium_1.ttf')
    }),
  ]);
}

function handleLoadingError(error) {
  console.warn(error);
}

function handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete) {
  setLoadingComplete(true);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 60,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: 'gotham-medium',
    fontSize: 36
  }
});
```

and then you have access to `fontFamily: 'gotham-medium'` anywhere in your app. Also you can resolve multiple promises *(load other assets, etc.)* within the `Promise.all()` call.

Let me know if that helped. Cheers!